# How to force label of a \caption{} to be lower case?

Tags: captions, koma-script, small-caps

The idea is to have the label of a caption (table in my case, but it shouldn't matter which one, really) to be in small caps and lowercase. Now, I managed to get them in the color that I want, and in small caps, and bold. But it still say's "Table 1" as label of the table, with a capital 'T'.

Hence, I'd like to have that in all lower case, so it looks good with small caps. I tried this:

I'm using something like this:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareCaptionFont{spot}{\color{spot}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{lc}{\lowercase}

\captionsetup{
    font=small,
    labelfont={sc,bf,spot,lc},
    labelsep=quad,
    indention=0pt,
    format=plain,
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I did something similar with the section labels:

```
\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\lowercase}
\addtokomafont{section}{\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\color{spot}\lowercase}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\rmfamily\mdseries\itshape\color{spot}}
```

Here, making the section title appear in lower case small caps worked fine.

But how to do that with captions for figures and tables?

---

The Text needs to be in **lowercase** *and* **small caps** for the desired effect.

Consider this example:
[image]
In this example, the section name "booktabs table" is actually lowercase. But because it's also made with `\scshape`, I get the effect that I want.

Now the label "Table 1" is in small caps, but it's not lowercase (hence the *big* 'T'). The desired effect is exactly what I've done with section names.

The relevant code section is:

```
\section{booktabs table}

\begin{table}[h] \centering
\ttabbox{%
    \caption{The Greek alphabet and variant letter forms with control sequences. Also, this lines needs to be much longer, so line breaks occur...\label{tab:greek}}
}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} \toprule
        \begin{tabular}{@{}clcl@{}}
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Uppercase}                  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Lowercase} \\ \midrule
                $\Alpha$   & \texttt{\textbackslash{}Alpha}   & $\mathrm\alpha$   & \texttt{\textbackslash{}alpha}   \\
                $\Beta$    & \texttt{\textbackslash{}Beta}    & $\mathrm\beta$    & \texttt{\textbackslash{}beta}    \\
                $\Gamma$   & \texttt{\textbackslash{}Gamma}   & $\mathrm\gamma$   & \texttt{\textbackslash{}gamma}   \\
        \end{tabular}
        \hspace{1em}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}rlrl@{}}
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Uppercase} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Lowercase} \\ \midrule
                $\Xi$      & \texttt{\textbackslash{}Xi}      & $\mathrm\xi$      & \texttt{\textbackslash{}xi}      \\
                $\Omicron$ & \texttt{\textbackslash{}Omicron} & $\mathrm\omicron$ & \texttt{\textbackslash{}digamma} \\
                $\color{white}0$ & & & \\
        \end{tabular} \\ \toprule
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccl@{}}
            Normal form & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Variant form} \\ \midrule
        \end{tabular}
        \hspace{1em}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccl@{}}
            Normal form & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Variant form} \\ \midrule
        \end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You're not talking about the caption label since it is the command `\label{}`.

Comment: Use `\renewcommand\tablename{\textsc{Table}}` for example.

Comment: Your code snippets contain quite a few macros -- such as `\Alpha`, `\Beta`, and `\Omicron` -- that would appear to be defined in one or more packages that are not mentioned anywhere in your setup. Please convert your code snippets into a compilable example that gives rise to the issues you're looking to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it has to be done with a custom label format:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{lc}{\MakeLowercase{#1}~#2}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc,labelformat=lc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{I'm the caption\label{tab:cap}}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            I'm inside the table \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This provides all lowercase + small caps labels. All other options are compatible (which aren't shown here).

Thanks to @Manuel for giving me the idea to use `\MakeLowercase{}` instead of `\lowercase`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't provide a minimal working example, I will answer here without it. As said in the comments renewing `\tablename` should do. However, since you only want the capital T as a lowercase I think `\renewcommand*\tablename{table}` should do. By the way, you shouldn't use `\lowercase` but `\MakeLowercase` which is a more LaTeXy and advanced approach.

And… I would define a `` \newcommand*\cmd[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}} `` and then use something more semantic like `\cmd{digamma}` or `\cmd{Xi}`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `\MakeLowercase`! I cannot redefine the word inside the label itself, as I need to have babel dependent labels there (for at least two languages). I think I got it now, though.

Comment: Again, that's something that must be explicitly written in the question (and why not a minimal compilable example?). Anyway, if you got it, it would be nice that you post the solution (again, it would be great if it was a self contained code that we could compile).

Comment: I'll post my answer with a compilable example shortly. I didn't need a fullu compilable example for this, as this is pretty much a rather simple issue and I don't expect anyone to code for me...

Comment: Not really “coding for you” (which, as you say, this is not the case) but basically to help anyone. I mean, what should I compile to reproduce your problem? I don't know (in fact it's not easy to reproduce the image you showed). And, in this case, I think that you only needed 3 or 4 more lines of code to make it compilable. It's a benefit for everyone. Many people don't answer just because they have nothing to start with.

Comment: `\textbackslash` will always result in a roman ("text") backslash, even if `\texttt` is intended.  to get a real "typewriter" backslash, this will work: `\texttt{\char``\\}` (that should be a single backtick after `\char` -- haven't yet mastered this coding in tex.sx comments).